# Document ready is not being called in javascript after RedirctToAction

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller method for displaying users in our system. I created a page to add users. To do this I'm using a view model and scaffolding. I have  a controller method to serve the page a controller method to handle the post.

After I handle the save I redirect back to the list page. I can see the list's controller method firing but it's document ready method isn't firing. The Document ready is where I use some ajax to load the list of users so it's not being refreshed. My post method looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewUser(EditPSUserModel model)
    {
        var manager = AdminConsoleHelper.createUserManager();
        AdminConsoleHelper.AddUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.IsAdmin, model.UserGroup, manager);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        }
```

so pretty basic stuff there. My List's page controller method looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
        [OutputCache(Duration=0)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            PSUsersModel m = new PSUsersModel();
            return View(m);
        }
```

I've tried playing with the output cache (setting it to NoStore and playing with the cache profile as well) but that doesn't seem to have any effect in getting the document ready to fire. I've also tried forcibly altering the datamodel on the index (list) controller method and it still stays cached.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

if it is just a caching issue then adding a date time stamp is a trick for that issue

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { date = DateTime.Now });
```

you don't need to use the date but since it is unique it will load a new version of the page

Comment: Still not working for me. I am going from the list page to the add user page from a link instead of an action. I don't think that would matter though. I can also click around the entire site and the changes don't show until I manually hit refresh.

Comment: This was a really good suggestion, I'm sure it'll come in handy as I figure my way through MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. Using this attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=0)]
```

caused my document ready to fire, I had to add it to the List's controller method. The other issue was that it was apparently caching my JSON calls, so my list wasn't being refreshed because the HTTPGet method I was using was cached. I added the same attribute as above to my HTTPGet method to get the user list and now it refreshes.